# React router exact matching only updating URL without re-render of DOM

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am connected to an API (The Movie DB) which is returning a list of results (Movies), and when I click into one of the results of the API I need to see a detail page. I have set up dynamic routing, however when I click for the detail page, my URL changes to something like: 'http://localhost:3000/moviedetails/2503', where the 2503 is a unique item ID. However, the DOM is not re-rendering. When I refresh with the same URL, I am then forwarded to the correct page - but I need this to happen upon the click of the link to the details page.

All questions I have seen online have stated that you must use the exact keyword within your routes to fix this, however I am using the exact keyword on all routes except the dynamic one, and still encountering the issue of the DOM not re-rendering.

My App.js file is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/About.js"
import Discover from './components/Discover';
import Favourites from './components/Favourites';
import Rated from './components/Rated';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import MovieDetails from './components/MovieDetails'

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/moviedetails/:id" component={MovieDetails}/>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route path="/discover" exact component={Discover} />
            <Route path="/favourites" exact component={Favourites} />
            <Route path="/rated" exact component={Rated} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My MovieRow.js (which includes the link to the details page) is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class MovieRow extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table key={this.props.movie.id}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img width="150" alt="poster" src={this.props.movie.poster_src} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <h3>{this.props.movie.title}</h3>
                <p>{this.props.movie.overview}</p>
                <Link to={`/moviedetails/${this.props.movie.id}`}>
                  View Movie Details
                </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default MovieRow;
```

My MovieDetails component (which is to be returned when link to details is clicked on) is not yet connected to the API and only contains the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class MovieDetails extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            movie details
          </div>
        );
      }

    }

    export default MovieDetails;
```

Comment: is the component is loading ? when you click on the particular movie i mean are you able to see movie details component

Comment: Have you tried using the `exact` keyword on the dynamic route?

Comment: can you create a minimum reproducable codesandbox so it will be helpful to find the problem and give a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi William welcome to the StackOverflow community:

Can you please check your console if you are getting any kind of error or something:

as this POC: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-dust-nrcrj works fine with the following components.

```
index.js
---------
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Rated from "../components/Rated";
import Home from "./Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/rated" exact component={Rated} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

```
Home.js
-------
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => props.history.push("/rated")}>GOTO RATED</button>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Home);
```

---

```
Rated.jsx
---------
import React from "react";

const Rated = () => <h1>Rated</h1>;
export default Rated;
```